# Connect as admin (sysdba) via SQLAlchemy - mode=2 does not work

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am using Python and SQLAlchemy; I would like to connect to an Oracle db as sysdba, is this possible?

when I pass the conection to create_engine, I also pass mode=2, so that should allow me to be equivalent to the sysdba.
But I get an error "ora01031".

```
connection = 'oracle://user:pwd@myhost:1521/SID?mode=2'
```

I tried without the mode=2 and my user log in without problems. But I need to be admin to access the system tables, which are hidden to regular users.
I tried to replace my username and password, with sysdba and the password that I use when I run SQLPlus, but via Python I get an auth error back from SQLAlchemy.

```
connection = 'oracle://sysdba:adminpwd@myhost:1521/SID'
```

Which is strange, because if I use sqlplus, I am authenticated without problems.

Am I forced to use cx_Oracle? or can I use SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the issue is the username that I was passing; this works

```
connection = 'oracle://sys:adminpwd@myhost:1521/SID?mode=2'
```

Hope it will save you hours wasted searching.